# Use of comma vs do-while in C macro

Tags: c, macros

Is there a downside to doing this:

```c
#define get_and_mark(name, b) get_val(name, &b), b = b | 0x80
```

rather than this:

```
#define get_and_mark(name, b) \
  do { \
    get_val(name, &b); \
    b = b | 0x80; \
  } while (0)
```

As far as I can see, the comma should also be safe for use in loops, branches etc.
But is it really?

Comment: You should clearly place some brackets around your subexpressions and around the whole expression in your first version. Think about what happens with `a = get_and_mark(name,b) & 0x10;`

Comment: If fixed up as @Gerhardh says, then the first can be used in an expression such as `if (get_and_mark(name, b) != 0)` but the second cannot.  Which semantic do you want?  Note that since `b` is mentioned multiple times in the expansion, you can't use `get_and_mark(name, b[i++])`.  Also note that you could use `(b) |= 0x80` for the assignment in both variants.  Why not use `static inline int get_and_mark(const char *name, int *b) { get_val(name, b); return (*b |= 0x80); }` — invoking it with `get_and_mark(name, &b)`?

Comment: Your `get_and_mark` appears to be intended to be used as a statement, when completed with `;`. However, `get_val(name, &b), b = b | 0x80` is an expression. So, if somebody accidentally uses it as an expression, the compiler will not report an error. This opportunity increases the probability of bugs in the software. In contrast, the `do { … } while (0)` form will yield an error if somebody accidentally uses it as a statement.

Comment: If you have a choice between spending five minutes making this an inline function, versus half an hour struggling to make it a macro, plus an additional several hours posting a question and waiting for answers on Stack Overflow, I would urge you in the **strongest** possible terms to go with the inline function.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments :-)

Do-while is the standard solution to grouping statements within macros. The culture around C programming involves strong opinions right up to language comitee and I just didn't know whether there's any reason to not mention the comma-way of going about it.

Comment: The macro prompting this question is much longer and converting it to a function would likely require adding an abstraction - maye a struct filled with pointers to avoid a very long parameter list - and wrapper functions to put into the struct.
The binary would be too big (can't inline pointer addresses from a struct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fixed up as [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263273/use-of-comma-vs-do-while-in-c-macro/74263969#comment131111209_74263273):

```
#define get_and_mark(name, b) (get_val(name, &(b)), (b) = (b) | 0x80)
```

then the first version can be used in an expression such as:

```
if (get_and_mark(name, b) != 0)
```

but the second cannot.  Which semantic do you want?  Do you want the invocation in an `if` condition to be a compile-time error?

Note that since `b` is mentioned multiple times in the expansion, you can't use `get_and_mark(name, b[i++])`.  Also, note that you could use `(b) |= 0x80` for the assignment in both variants:

```
#define get_and_mark(name, b) (get_val(name, &(b)), (b) |= 0x80)

#define get_and_mark(name, b) \
    do { \
        get_val(name, &(b)); \
        (b) |= 0x80; \
    } while (0)
```

You could use the comma operator in the second variant — though there's no need to do so.

Why not use an inline function?

```
static inline int get_and_mark(const char *name, int *b)
{
    get_val(name, b);
    return (*b |= 0x80);
}
```

You'd invoke it with `get_and_mark(name, &b)`?  (Obviously, I'm guessing at the type of `name`, but fixing that if I'm wrong is easy.)